# Is there a way to change the width/thickness of the vaxis baseline in google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to make the vaxis baseline in my combo chart to be thicker/bolder.

I'm able to change the color with the code below

```
vAxis: {
    baselineColor: '#FFA500',
},
```

Is there a way to change the width?

Answer (score 2):

no standard options for changing the thickness of the baseline,
but it can be changed on the chart's `'ready'` event.

since you're changing the color,
the color can be used to find the baseline `<rect>` element.
but need to make sure the color you're looking for is all lowercase.
(the chart changes any color options to lowercase)

to change the thickness, add attributes for `'stroke'` and `'stroke-width'`

```
baseline.setAttribute('stroke', options.vAxis.baselineColor)
baseline.setAttribute('stroke-width', '10')
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      baselineColor: '#ffa500',
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(baseline) {
      if (baseline.getAttribute('fill') === options.vAxis.baselineColor) {
        baseline.setAttribute('stroke', options.vAxis.baselineColor)
        baseline.setAttribute('stroke-width', '10')
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```